# Adding a metabox shortcode "paypal accept payment" in my custom post type back-end

Tags: metabox, paypal

I have created a science journal with annotum theme, now I want users to pay when they publish an article, but I don't have programming skills to do this when they click publish to pay with paypal, so I want to create a meta box in my custom post type: articles that contains a WP Easy Paypal Payment Accept widget in admin area of article post type. In dashboard admin area I have created this widget by this code (with shortcode: `Paypal_payment_accept();) :`

```
  function wpc_dashboard_widget_function() {
    // Entering the text between the quotes
    echo Paypal_payment_accept();
   }
   function wpc_add_dashboard_widgets() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('wp_dashboard_widget', 'Technical information',        'wpc_dashboard_widget_function');
   }
   add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpc_add_dashboard_widgets' );
```

So the question clearly is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use [add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your child theme / plugin functions.php. I think this should do the trick. Let me know

```
function your_meta_callback( $post ) {
 echo Paypal_payment_accept();
}

add_meta_box( 'your_meta', __( 'Meta Box Title', 'your-textdomain' ), 'your_meta_callback', 'your-posttype-name', 'side' );
```

For more information see Wordpress Codex on [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

---

Update:
Ok I have looked into this. If we nest any form into the post editor form, we will run into problems as there will be two submits and other things. So the best approach would be to use a modal (native jQuery popup of Wordpress). So based on your source code from the comment I would change it to be the following:

```
function wpt_article_pay() {
 global $pagenow,$typenow;

 //Enqueue the required script to use a modal
 add_thickbox();

 //Check if you are on the correct page 
 if (!in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' ) ))
    return;

 /* Add a link to open the modal (uses the inlineID) to open the code we
 later add in the footer */
 echo '<a href="#TB_inline?height=155&width=300&inlineId=your-paypal-modal" class="thickbox">PayPal</a>';
}

//Enqueue the inline form to be displayed in the modal.
function enqueue-your-paypal-modal(){
    global $pagenow,$typenow;   
    if (!in_array( $pagenow, array( 'post.php', 'post-new.php' )))
        return;
?>
<div id="your-paypal-modal" style="display:none">
    <?php echo paypal_payment_accept(); ?>
</div>
<?php
}

add_filter('admin_footer','enqueue-your-paypal-modal');
```

This will ensure that you have a working paypal button, but it WONT have the correct return URL defined as you can only define one in the Plugin settings. As well you can't define that it should open in a new window. I don't know if you feel comfortable enough to do this, but I would suggest to look into the button API of paypal and maybe create the button yourself: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#id08A9E900IEX

Comment: i have done this way: firt i have added this code in my custom post type article function:  `'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_events_metaboxes' `

later i have added this code in my childtheme functions.php:

`function add_article_metaboxes( ) {


 add_meta_box(  'wpt_article_pay', 'Pay to Publish', 'wpt_article_pay', 'article', 'side', 'high' );

}

function wpt_article_pay() {
 global $article;

 echo Paypal_payment_accept();
} `

then this happens: look at the photo: http://imgur.com/ow3sqqg
so if you don't know this please tell me how to add a link in this wiget.